# using environment variables in docker

Tags: docker, environment-variables, versioning, dockerfile

I can run alpine with node 4 version 4.6.0:

```
docker run mhart/alpine-node:4 node --version v4.6.0
```

How can I put this into Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:4 node --version v4.6.0
```

How can I use environment variables to replace :{4} and version {v4.6.0}?

So that I can change the node version?

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg
?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that a valid `Dockerfile` must have [`FROM`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) as its first instruction, you *cannot* use docker [`build --build-arg <varname>=<value>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg), as it relies on `ARG` declarations which are done *after* `FROM`.

So you need to generate your Dockerfile through a script which takes the version as an argument and a `Dockerfile.template` (template file, with `@VERSION@` placeholder for instance) in order to get the right `Dockerfile`.